# Perl modules: MySQL vs DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, performance, module, dbi

A lot of our automated processes use perl and need to access our MySQL DBs.  I hate to admit it, but up until recently we haven't really done much benchmarking with the majority of our processes.  One of our devs setup a test to compare the performance of "use MySQL" vs "use DBI" with the following pseudocode:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
  pull and store all records in a 4,000 record table
}
```

Results:
MySQL - 57s, 56s, 57s
DBI - 43s, 42s, 43s

For some reason I was surprised to see DBI performing so much better; considering how little I know about either of the modules.  I realize that there are likely several things wrong with the benchmark that was run and that everyone's setups/results are going to very but I was curious whether others have experienced any sort of performance gain by using DBI vs the MySQL module.

Comment: DBI is the de-facto database module for Perl. I'm not aware of any other MySQL modules. Even Oracle does not speak of any other module: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/apis-perl.html

Comment: Could you give us full names and URLs of the exact modules you're referring to?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to find any info (e.g. URLs, etc) about them but for whatever it is worth their paths are: /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Mysql.pm and /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/mysql.pm

Comment: yes I'm very confused esp considering searching cpan for mysql returns the DBI DBD for it first.

Comment: That benchmark is meaningless w/o more information.  How many runs? Server load? # of connections? Memory utilization percentage?

Comment: @vol7ron Sorry for the lack of information; I tried to provide everything I had access to at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [MySQL](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-3.0007/lib/Mysql.pm) module he's referring to, it [was](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql-3.0007/) part of the [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/) dist. To quote it

> As of Msql-Mysql-modules 1.19_10
>   M(y)sqlPerl is no longer a separate
>   module. Instead it is emulated using
>   the DBI drivers. You are strongly
>   encouraged to implement new code with
>   DBI directly.

So the emulation layer is the reason for your performace loss. Also that the `MySQL.pm` was removed in 4.x line of DBD::mysql, it last appeared in 2006.

Comment: Your link is dead.  I found http://search.cpan.org/~rudy/DBD-mysql-2.9008/lib/Mysql.pm