# Is DBI the only way to access databases in Perl

Tags: database, perl

Is `DBI` the only way to access a database in Perl?

Are there any other wrappers besides `DBI` available that can be used to access databases like `MS-SQL/Oracle/MySQL`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419468/perl-modules-mysql-vs-dbi

Comment: Are you just curious, or is there a problem with DBI that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Just curious. And I find it surprising that there isn't any. If someone could explain why there is not may...that would be interesting.

Comment: There are wrappers around DBI...search for 'perl dbi orm', e.g. DBIx::Class, Rose::DB::Object

Comment: DBI is a case of “Tim Toady Bicarbonate”: There are many ways to use databases, but consistency (here: DBI) is a good thing too. However, NoSQL-databases tend to use non-DBI modules (MongoDB being the prime example). The Perl Core still has the `dbmopen` function, even if it's a bit deprecated. And you can always shell out, e.g. ``@rows = map{chomp; [split/\t/]} `mysql -B -D database -e 'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = $injection_attack'`;`` or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a moment, try and imagine the hardware market for personal computers *before* Windows. For example, in those days, each application needed to have its own drivers. That meant that if a printer did not have drivers for both [WordStar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordStar) and [Lotus 1-2-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3), it was pretty much useless in an office environment. What if you had a printer that worked with both of those applications, but you now wanted output from [Harvard Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Graphics) as well? You needed to ensure that *the application itself* knew how to handle your specific printer.

That is, *N* applications and *M* printers meant needing *N*×*M* drivers.

With Windows, a hardware manufacturer could write a driver for Windows, and so long as an application knew how to talk to a printer via the interface provided by Windows, it did not need to know anything about the specific hardware.

This made both hardware and software cheaper. Specifically, application programmers did not need to know as much about specific hardware that existed. And, hardware that did not exist at the time the application was written could still be used with the application if they both communicated through the same driver interface.

Of course, this is a rather simplified look at the situation. Even with DOS, there was [ESC/P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P), [PCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language), and, of course, [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), so it wasn't like every single printer was unique, but the application still needed to be aware of such details.

The situation is similar here. Perl applications that know how to talk to [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI), for the most part, need not concern themselves with most of the various details of each particular database. Making a specific database available to Perl programs requires no more than writing the appropriate [DBD::*](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=dbd&mode=module) module for it. The following figure from [DBI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Architecture_of_a_DBI_Application) illustrates this:

```
             |<- Scope of DBI ->|
                  .-.   .--------------.   .-------------.
  .-------.       | |---| XYZ Driver   |---| XYZ Engine  |
  | Perl  |       | |   `--------------'   `-------------'
  | script|  |A|  |D|   .--------------.   .-------------.
  | using |--|P|--|B|---|Oracle Driver |---|Oracle Engine|
  | DBI   |  |I|  |I|   `--------------'   `-------------'
  | API   |       | |...
  |methods|       | |... Other drivers
  `-------'       | |...
                  `-'
```

Once the `DBI` is there, the incentive to write or use a specific, dedicated module for a given engine is reduced. Sure, there might be certain benefits to having a standalone module to communicate solely with that `ABC` engine somewhere out there, but those benefits must be weighed against the costs. Programmers whose applications need database access face the need to learn the ins and outs of an unfamiliar API. If the only way of accessing the `ABC` engine is via something other than `DBI`, then the `ABC` engine does not allow programmers to leverage what they already know. Either an application using the `ABC` engine's dedicated API becomes impossible to use with other engines, or the application programmer must come with her own database independent interface, and program to that, and replicate the `DBD` to `DBI` layer. But, why bother with that when there already is an established database independent interface and its accompanying database drivers?

Take a look at the engine specific portions of [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/) and imagine how much more work it would have been if we did not already have a `DBD` for each of those engines. Then, imagine if [Rose::DB](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB) had to duplicate the entire set of drivers also.

Or, you can imagine what would happen if every house had its preferred type of wall socket and every appliance had its own preferred power plug. Every laptop can have its own transformer, but we all benefit from a having standard plugs and sockets from which they can draw electricity. `DBI` is at the plug-and-socket level.